# msearch call in elastic fails with key[size] is not supported for the metadata section

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is the request payload for the msearch post call :-

```
{"search_type":"query_then_fetch","ignore_unavailable":true,"index":"*****"}
    {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "1710391896481",
              "lte": "1710413496481",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "query": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "fixed_interval": "30s",
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "1710391896481",
          "max": "1710413496481"
        },
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "aggs": {}
    }
    }
    }
```

This fails only once , during page load , after that the same api works fine.

Error from API

```
{ "error": { "root_cause": [ { "type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "key [size] is not supported in the metadata section" } ], "type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "key [size] is not supported in the metadata section" }, "status": 400 }
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips to improve search speed.

1. Remove `query_string` because it's filtering everything with `*`.
2. Decrease the number of buckets in the aggs results.

> 1710413496481 - 1710391896481 = 21.600.000 ms = 21.600 seconds

> 21.600 seconds / 30s per bucket = 720 buckets

> To decrease the number of buckets you can increase the `fixed_interval` in `date_histogram`
> aggs or decrease the time differences between `max` and `min`
> timestamps.

Comment: thanks for the inputs , for now my primary issue is the api failure(see below)



{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "key [size] is not supported in the metadata section"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "key [size] is not supported in the metadata section"
    },
    "status": 400
}

Comment: You're welcome, please open another question for that and let me try to help you in there.